# Trying to build a jar of my project with external (and probably badly added) libraries on intellij

Tags: java, maven, javafx, jar, jfreechart

I'm trying to build a .jar of my project in order to be able to start it without using IDE/shell, and maybe permit usage on different machines and OS.

I'm using intellij, and the .jar i produced up until now gives me the following error:

```
Sep 07, 2023 6:03:47 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @228575c0'
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:263)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:671)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:275)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:671)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
```

I imagine the problem is how I included the libraries in my project. I'm using javafx and jfreechart, and since I'm not an expert on library usage, i googled a lot to be able to use them, and I stopped as soon as sample code started working, and in the end:

- I downloaded javafx on my computer, included it by using File > Project Structure > Libraries and using the local address
- I included jfreechart building the project with maven

I'm not used to working with libraries, so I apologize for my complete ignorance and if I'm not using the correct terminology.

I don't know what I should do: try and include the libraries properly? How? Add some magic line of code to the mop that's gonna solve my problems?

Comment: For maven, the `pom.xml` file is what matters. It's an XML configuration file, so sections are grouped by their parent node (e.g. `<project><name>MyProject</name><version>1.0.0</version></project>`). When you look up a maven dependency online, there will usually be a `<dependency>` xml tag you can add under `<dependencies>` in order to automatically download, link, and build with other libraries. No manual file management needed, but a little reading/learning of maven in general.

Comment: Building a runnable jar file with JavaFX is not supported. See the various links in the  "Packaging" section in the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).

Comment: [`jfree-fxdemos`](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-fxdemos) shows one approach; [_discussion #374_](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/discussions/374) mentions using [tag:jfreechart] in a _modular_ context suitable for `jlink`.

Comment: An unsupported approach is: [Maven Shade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing).

Comment: If you go modular, [`javafx:jlink`](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin#javafxjlink-options) in the _javafx-maven-plugin_ offers a convenient way to invoke `jlink`.